# Combine data from several forms Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have 3 different forms like so:

```
class Questions(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['life_areas', 'life_desires', 'life_ambitions',]        

class BasicContact(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['status', 'first_name', 'email_address', 'country',]

class PhoneContact(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['phone_number', 'best_time', 'preferences',]
```

I have created a form wizard that gathers information using these three forms.

```
FORMS = [("questions", Questions),
     ("basiccontact", BasicContact),
     ("phonecontact", PhoneContact),]

class ClientFormWizard(SessionWizardView):
    form_list = FORMS
    def done(self, form_list, form_dict, **kwargs):
        # get data from the forms
        questions = form_dict['questions']
        basiccontact = form_dict['basiccontact']
        phonecontact = form_dict['phonecontact']

        formdata = dict(questions.items() + basiccontact.items() + phonecontact.items())

        clientform = ClientForm(formdata)
        new_client = clientform.save()

        # return redirect(...)
```

I am basically trying to concatenate the information from the three forms into a single ClientForm and then save it. However, I am not sure how to concatenate information from the three forms. I tried doing it the dictionary way, but it didn't work. What is the best way to accomplish this sort of concatenation?

EDIT: After reading the Form API docs, I finally figured it out. This is how I aggregated the info from the 3 forms:

```
    formdata = dict()
    for f in form_list:
        formdata.update(f.cleaned_data)
```

form_list contains instances of all the forms submitted. And we just extract this information and put it into a new dictionary called formdata. After that, it works.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using three different forms for the same model?

Comment: I was reading up on wizardforms here: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#how-to-work-with-modelform-and-modelformset). I don't know how else to partition it into three sets of forms.

Comment: Ah. So basically you want to present the forms at separate times. Having never used the form wizard, I'm not the best person to answer, but if memory serves, you'll need to supply your aggregated data to `ClientForm` as `ClientForm(data=formdata)`

Comment: Yes, but my problem is I don't know how to aggregate the data. I tried it as shown in the code and it doesn't work.

Comment: Without knowing the complexities of the SessionWizardView, I may be providing an ignorant opinion, but you can always just separate your code into three separate views and persist your form data in session, combining it at the end.

Comment: That's exactly what SessionWizardView does. It's basically just a convenient way of doing just that. I just need to figure out how to combine the information I got in form_list. Tried many things; didn't work.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to be of more help.

Comment: Instead of `some_form.items()` try `some_form.cleaned_data` when concatenating the data. EDIT: Ah, see that you figured out exactly that. I'll go ahead and post an answer so others can easily see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `some_form.items()`, use `some_form.cleaned_data`, which will return a dictionary of the validated POST data.

So, as you figured out, it would read:

```
FORMS = [("questions", Questions),
     ("basiccontact", BasicContact),
     ("phonecontact", PhoneContact),]

class ClientFormWizard(SessionWizardView):
    form_list = FORMS
    def done(self, form_list, form_dict, **kwargs):
        # get data from the forms

        form_data = dict()
        for form in form_list:
            form_data.update(form.cleaned_data)

        clientform = ClientForm(form_data)
        new_client = clientform.save()

        # return redirect(...)
```